# WebApi "The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE"

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Using WebApi angularjs project and trying to delete function as
`

```
     [HttpDelete]
    public String DeleteCountry(string cntryId)
    {
        if (cntryId != null)
        {
            return repoCountry.DeleteCountry(Convert.ToInt32(cntryId));

        }
        else
        {
            return "0";

        }
    }
```

js function is

```
  $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: '/api/Country/DeleteCountry/',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { cntryId: cntryId }
        }).then(function (response) {});
```

Here I am  getting exception

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."}
```

Insertion,update and get functionalities are working correctly.Giv a solution and why it is happening for delete only

Comment: Can you try to remove the 'data' object and append the cntryId to the url? My guess is the ASP.NET routing is trying to find a HttpDelete action without parameters (since there are non in the url).

Comment: The parameter is not marked as [FromBody], so it must be placed in the URL if I recall it right.

Comment: @Gusman that's correct, by default binding looks for "simple" types from the URL query parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adorn your method with the `Route` attribute (I see this give me more control on the routing behavior in web API) and pass your data parameters as constructor args in this format: `[HttpDelete, Route("{cntryId}")`:

```
[HttpDelete, Route("{cntryId}")]
public String DeleteCountry(string cntryId)
  {
    //....
  }
```

in the angular controller, you can just do this:

```
$http.delete('/api/Country/' + cntryId).then(function (response) {
            //if you're waiting some response
        })
```

Comment: you don't need {cntryId} if you havn't change the webapiconfig

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel you would need the route attribute unless you changed the default route from {id} to {cntryId} in the api config. Otherwise, any parameter that isn't named 'id' will route as a query string.

Answer (score 1):

is not a webapi issue is more a the format of your query . 
the message says that `does not support http method 'DELETE'` because the webapi delete method is expecting an id as a parameter. and the route has the following format    `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",`
to resolve your issue try to  use fiddler to intercept your request and ensure that your delete request  is sent as  `'/api/Country/DeleteCountry/'+cntryId,`

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and solved it finally. This is simple and stupid solution.

Earlier code

```
public String DeleteCountry(string cntryId)
```

Changed code

```
public String DeleteCountry(int id)
```

so just use 'int id' not 'cntryId'. I did not use [HttpDelete] before method name but it worked.

Comment: OMG. I wasted three hours. I stumbled across this and thought, "nah!, that can't be it."

Changed my variable type from int to string and it started working.  No particular reason that I could think of, but that's what solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$http({
   method: "delete",
   url: '/api/Country/Country?cntryId=' + cntryId,
}).then(function (response) {});
```

Option 2:

```
public String DeleteDeleteCountry([FromBody]string cntryId)
{
    if (cntryId != null)
    {
        return repoCountry.DeleteCountry(Convert.ToInt32(cntryId));

    }
    else
    {
        return "0";

    }
}
```

Best Option:

API

```
[Route("{countryId}")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int countryId)
{
    try
    {
       repoCountry.DeleteCountry(countryId);
    }
    catch (RepoException ex)
    {
       if (ex == notfound)
          this.NotFound();
       if (ex == cantdelete)
          this.Confict();
       this.InternalServerError(ex.message);
    }
    return this.Ok();
}
```

Javascript

```
$http({
   method: "delete",
   url: '/api/country/' + cntryId,
}).then(function (response) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that u did not change the default routing. Same error can happen if u fail to declare [HttpDelete] attribute for the action in webAPI. Please try following

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will usually happen if you are trying to do a `PUT` or a `DELETE` and you don't have the API configured to allow it.

This post shows you how to solve this 405 error and get it working properly.

The easiest way to edit the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 line in the `web.config` file of the Web API project

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```